# Overwrite global ajax event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two global ajax event handlers:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function() { /* do something... */ });
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() { /* do something... */ });
```

I want to overwrite only the ajaxComplete event handler for a specific ajax call.

Do I have to set `global: false` for the specific ajax call and then define the ajaxSend Event handler for this call or is there another way to just overwrite the ajaxComplete event handler?

Comment: May I ask why you want to override the ajaxComplete callback?

Comment: "Do I have to set `global: false`?", why not just try it and see what happens

Comment: I have several Ajax calls in my application. With the ajaxComplete I globally hide a loading panel that shows up when executing the ajax call. But there is one specific case where I do not want the loading panel to disappear after completing the ajax call. But I still want the global ajaxSend function to be called.

Comment: sounds like you have answered your own question while asking it

Comment: I just hopped there is a more elegant way without having to define the ajaxSend event twice.